# How to let gradle build dependent sub-project first when using non-compile dependencies

Tags: gradle

How can I tell gradle to build a certain sub-projects first, even though I don't have a compile dependency to them? How are project dependencies handled internally?

Example:

**settings.gradle**:

```
include "app", "schema"
```

**build.gradle**:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

**schema/build.gradle**:

```
// empty
```

**app/build.gradle**:

```
configurations {
    schemas
}

dependencies {
    schemas project(":schema")
    schemas "org.example:example-schema:1.0"
}

task extractSchema(type: Copy) {
    from {
        configurations.schemas.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    into "build/schemas"
}

//compileJava.dependsOn extractSchema
```

And when running:

```
$ cd app
$ gradle extractSchema
```

I get:

```
Cannot expand ZIP 'schema/build/libs/schema.jar' as it does not exist.
```

What I want is that gradle automatically builds all sub-projectes defined in the **configurations.schemas** dependency list first (if they are projects).

Note: I want to be able to share the extractSchema task across multiple gradle projects, so it is important that gradle takes the list of sub-project to be built first from the **configurations.schemas** list.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html? You could make extractSchema dependent on the tasks that generate the schemas, e.g. `task extractSchema(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':schema:assemble') `

Comment: But the thing is that I don't want to hardcode the dependency. Gradle should be able to resolve the dependency from the configurations.schemas list automatically and resolve/build them first.

Comment: Maybe you can use http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:buildDependencies for your depends on, based on the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle build order is never on the project level, but always on the task level. `from(configuration.schemas)` would infer task dependencies automatically, but in case of `from(configuration.schemas.collect { ... })`, this doesn't work because the resulting value is no longer `Buildable`. Adding `dependsOn configurations.schemas` should solve the problem.

Comment: So `task extractSchema(type: Copy, dependsOn: configurations.schemas) { ...`